# Getting a error No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift3

I am writing the code in swift 3 and Xcode 8.

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CashTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString

    var newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString

    var newTextString = String(newText)

    let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits
    var digitText = ""
    for c in newTextString.unicodeScalars {
        if digits.contains(c) {
            digitText.append(String(c))
        }
    }

    // Format the new string
    if let numOfPennies = Int(digitText) {
        newText = "$" + self.dollarStringFromInt(numOfPennies)+ "." + self.centsStringFromInt(numOfPennies)

    } else {
        newText = "$0.00"
    }

    textField.text = newText as String

    return false
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text!.isEmpty {
        textField.text = "$0.00"
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true;
}

func dollarStringFromInt(value: Int) -> String {
    return String(value / 100)
}

func centsStringFromInt(value: Int) -> String {

    let cents = value % 100
    var centsString = String(cents)

    if cents < 10 {
        centsString = "0" + centsString
    }

    return centsString
}

}
```

for this line of code from above :

```
newText = "$" + self.dollarStringFromInt(numOfPennies) + "." + self.centsStringFromInt(numOfPennies)
```

I get a error like this:

```
No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSString'.
```

Unable to resolve this error.

Any help with little explanation would be appreciated

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail. Show how all relevant variables and functions are declared.

Comment: Just use [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Swift 2, `NSString` and `String` aren't automatically converted between each other.

Try something like this:

```
newText = ("$" + self.dollarStringFromInt(numOfPennies) + "." + self.centsStringFromInt(numOfPennies)) as NSString
```

You can further clean this up by using a consistent type-- either `String` or `NSString` throughout (e.g. changing function returns, etc).

Comment: Followed what you said and did this.But also added the value label. It got me solved . newText = ("$" + self.dollarStringFromInt(value: numOfPennies) + "." + self.centsStringFromInt(value:numOfPennies)) as NSString